# Switching icon in AngularJS with different functions

Tags: angularjs

[image: Bookmark button]

What to put in ng-click to follow the functions in my controller

`view.html`:

```
  <a class="tab-item" ng-click="addBookmark('{{singleRecipe[0].recipe_id}}')">
    <i ng-class="{'icon ion-ios-pricetag': marked,'icon ion-ios-pricetag-outline' :!marked}" ng-click="marked=!marked"></i>Bookmark
  </a>
```

Every click of the icon the action should be different
`controller.js`:

```
$scope.newBookmark={};
$scope.newBookmark.userID =  $scope.userdata.user_id;
$scope.addBookmark = function(recipe_id)
{
  $scope.newBookmark.recipeID = recipe_id;
  console.log($scope.newBookmark);
  if (!BookmarkList.add){
    BookmarkList.delfave($scope.newBookmark);
    console.log(BookmarkList.delfave);
  }else{
    BookmarkList.add($scope.newBookmark);
    console.log(BookmarkList.add);
  }
};
```

Comment: Your html doesn't really match up with your controller code. What exactly do you want to happen, and what is it doing currently?

Comment: what i want is that if the first click adds bookmark the second click should remove bookmark but as of now the first and the second click adds bookmark

Answer (score 1):

What you might want to do is have two links, one to add to bookmark and one to remove the bookmark and have them ng-if'd or ng-show'd.

Eg:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="addBookmark()" ng-if="!bookmarked">Add to bookmark</a>
<a href="#" ng-click="removeBookmark()" ng-if="bookmarked">Remove bookmark</a>
```

Comment: Usually is better to use `ng-show` instead of `ng-if` because `ng-if` create own scope (and result may wonder you)

Comment: but i want it to be in the same <a> in which icon switches

Comment: @Sandy, why do you want it in the same a tag? Won't the end result be the same?